# Azure durable function - Python SDK - trigger Activity Function from Client Function

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am preparing automation solution in Azure. I decided to use Azure Durable Functions. As per Durable Functions design I have created: Client Function (triggered by Service Bus message), Activity Function, Orchestrator Function. Service bus message is in `Json` format. Once Client Function get Service Bus message Client Function has to run Orchestrator Function. I have prepared code in Python, but does not work. In Azure function `Code + test` window getting an error.`500 Internal Server Error`. My code below. Main problem here is to run Orchestrator Python Function from Client Function code presented below. Piece of code for receiving service bus json message is ok, I tested it i other functions.

```
import json
import azure.functions as func
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
import azure.durable_functions as df

async def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage, starter: str):

    result = ({
        'body': json.loads(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8')) 
    })

    try:
        account_name = result.get('body', {}).get('accountName')

        client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
        instance_id = await client.start_new(msg.route_params["Orchestrator"], None, None)

        logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(e)
```

Solution workflow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While starting the instance of the orchestration function using the `start_new` method, it will need both payload and messages.

You have given the message in the following code:

```
instance_id = await client.start_new(msg.route_params["Orchestrator"], None, None)
```

Adding the payload, might work and by payload, I mean this

```
payload = msg.get_body().decode('utf-8')
```

The code will look like

```
 instance_id = await client.start_new(msg.route_params["Orchestrator"], payload)
```

refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=python,2x-durable-functions#orchestration-client).

Also refer this [article](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/ajitpatra365crm/posts/using-service-bus-triggered-azure-durable-function-with-d365-ce) by Ajit Patra

Comment: I added code modifications you suggested but still does not work as expected.